# Do the Elf Blood racial trait allow you to fulfil "being an elf" prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, racial-traits

In Pathfinder, half-elves have the following racial trait:

> **Elf Blood**: Half-elves count as both elves and humans for any effect related to race.

Since now I always considered that it meant that a half-elf could for example be an [Ancient Lorekeeper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf/ancient-lorekeeper-oracle-elf/) which is "available to elven oracles", or a [Brightness Seeker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/brightness-seeker) which has "race: elf" as a prerequisite.

But it seems to me more and more odd that this is possible, on top of the other stuff that is specifically designed for half-elves.

What is the official ruling on the subject? Can a half-elf took an archetype, a prestige class, a feat or other stuff with "being an elf" as a prerequisite?

As a sidenote I deliberately didn't put "elf" as a tag since the same question could be asked for any race with the "X blood" racial trait (eg half-orcs).

Comment: [Related] [Can a half-elf take human traits?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102003) • [Do Half-elves count as Humans for the Favored Enemy class feature?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50370)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, hybrid races can take options designed for either of their parent races, as well as options designed specifically for their race. It’s one of the reasons half-elves are so potent (many say overpowered) in Pathfinder (half-orcs less so, since the orc and half-orc options aren’t nearly as good as elf or half-elf options).

From the FAQ, we have a rule that [hybrid races may freely select from “rules elements” of both parent races](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qf9):

> #### Half-Elf or Half-Orc: Can a character of either of these races select human racial archetypes (such as from Advanced Race Guide?
>
> Yes. Half-elves and half-orcs may select racial favored class options, archetypes, traits, and so on, as if they were a full member of both races (a half-elf can select elf and human rules elements, a half-orc can select human and orc rules elements).
>
> Edit 9/26/13: This is a reversal of an earlier ruling. This resolves a discrepancy between this FAQ and two *Advanced Player's Guide* FAQs.

Note that a racial archetype, like ancient lorekeeper, is explicitly listed here. Frustratingly, feats are *not* explicitly mentioned, but those would certainly be a “rule element” and a fairly similar (as far as prerequisites are concerned) to traits, which are mentioned explicitly, so feats are presumably covered by “and so on.”

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but a frequent one and the other answer has missed a decisive rule from the [Advanced Race Guide](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Humanoid%20(0%20RP)&Category=Type%20Quality):

> Every humanoid creature also has a subtype to match its race, such as human, giant, goblinoid, reptilian, or tengu. If you are making a new humanoid race, you should either find an existing subtype to match or make a new one by using the name of the race as the subtype. If you are making a halfbreed race, it should have the racial type of both parent races. For example, a half-elf has both the human and the elf subtypes. Subtypes are often important to qualify for other racial abilities and feats. **If a humanoid has a racial subtype, it is considered a member of that race in the case of race prerequisites.**

This passage from the race creation rules should settle matters conclusively.

As for your example, since Half-Elves are Humanoids with the "Elf" and "Human" subtypes, they qualify for all character options, that have "Elf" as a prerequisite just like a "normal" Elf.

This also renders the "Elf Blood" racial trait of Half-Elves moot, since their subtypes includes that effect already; the trait now only matters when a Half-Elf changes creature type to something other than Humanoid (e.g. Outsider as a 20th-level Monk).